# EnumMap and Java Generics

Tags: java, generics, enums

Suppose I have two enums:

```
enum MyEnum {A, B, C};
enum YourEnum {D, E, F};
```

and two very similar classes:

```
class MyRow {
  EnumMap<MyEnum, Object> map;
}

class YourRow {
  EnumMap<YourEnum, Object> map;
}
```

Is there a way to do something like this instead?

```
class Row<T implements Enum> {
  EnumMap<T, Object> map;
}
```

so that I can say `Row<MyEnum>` or `Row<YourEnum>`? I just don't want to have to define a new Row class for each of these specific enums (I have dozens).

Comment: what is `Enum` here `T implements Enum`

Comment: `Map<Enum<?>, Object> whatever`.

Comment: Where are you stuck? The class signature you posted compiles, and can be used as you describe, can it not?

Comment: What about `class Row<T extends Enum<T>>` ?

Comment: The "T extends Enum<T>" is the apparently the trick for this problem. Using implements gave me errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your example it looks like you may be looking form something like

```
class Row<T extends Enum<T>> {
    EnumMap<T, Object> map;
}
```

You can use this class for instance like

```
Row<MyEnum> row = new Row<>();
row.map.put(MyEnum.A, "foo");//OK
//row.map.put(YourEnum.D, "bar");// Error, `put` from this reference 
                                 // is meant to handle `MyEnum`
```

---

> inside the Row class, it doesn't seem to let me loop through values in the standard way:
>
> `for (T col : T.values())`

`T` is generic type which is [erased at runtime](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) to `Object` and Object doesn't have `values()` method. Maybe you should consider including `Class<T>` field which would store information at runtime which exactly Enum you are using. This class has `getEnumConstants()` method which is similar to `values()` method.

So your code can look like

```
class Row<T extends Enum<T>> {
    EnumMap<T, Object> map;
    Class<T> enumType;

    public Row(Class<T> enumType){
        this.enumType = enumType;
    }

    void showEnums(){
        for (T col : enumType.getEnumConstants())
            System.out.println(col);
    }
}
```

and can be used for example this way

```
Row<MyEnum> row = new Row<>(MyEnum.class);
row.showEnums();
```

Comment: A quick followup ... inside the Row class, it doesn't seem to let me loop through values in the standard way: `for (T col : T.values())`. Is there some way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Please try like this

```
public class Row<T extends Enum<T>> {

    EnumMap<T, Object> objs;
}
```